# 無料枠のChatGPT3のAPIについて

Tags: api, chatgpt

ChatGPT3のAPIの無料枠があるって本当ですか？友達が言ってたので詳しくは分かりませんが

Comment: 現時点の検索で新しいと思われる使ってみた的な記事はこちら。[OpenAI APIとは？使い方を実際の手順を紹介しながら解説](https://www.value-domain.com/media/openai/), [OpenAIのplaygroundを無料枠で遊んでみた](https://note.com/kwatogo/n/n22fb0411093b)

Answer (score 1):

> ChatGPT3のAPIの無料枠があるって本当ですか？友達が言ってたので詳しくは分かりませんが

上記がトライアル期間のことを指しているのであれば、2023/9/17現在存在するようです。

[Pricing](https://openai.com/pricing)
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

規約は改定されることがありますので最新の情報はOpenAIのサイトを確認してください。
（以前は18ドル分の無料クレジットありましたが、2023/3からは5ドルに変更されています）

参考：[ChatGPTのAPIを使う前に知っておくべき利用料金と「トークン」の考え方、注意点](https://otona-life.com/2023/05/24/173094/)